# MS access tables relationships trouble

Tags: database, ms-access, datatables, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have a database with three tables: Employees, courses and instructors.

I am having toubles making the relationships because some of the employees can be instructors. So how should I link my tables so that I can add some of the employees to be instructors. Also what would be the the primary and foreign keys that I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, some but not all of your instructors are also employees. There are two ways to go about it:

No data duplication: No `Instructors` or `Employees` tables, just a `Person` table with `Yes/No` fields for `IsInstructor` and `IsEmployee`.

Data duplication (if current scheme is fixed or the remaining info for instructors and employees is very different): Add an `EmployeeID` field to the `Instructors` table, leaving it `Null` if the instructor is not also an employee.

In all cases the primary key is an `auto-increment number` for each table (`PersonID`, `EmployeeID`, `InstructorID`, `CourseID`) and that is the only field used in the various relationships.